# SQL Query of a column containing an XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am trying to extract data From a column that contains an XML. I have tried searching but can't seem to get it right. The column name is Settings and here is some of one of the xmls in the column. I am trying to get the value for the MacAddress entries for all xmls in the column. The table is called Hardware.Thanks for any help.

I have tried this query which returns all values.

```
    select uri, settings.value('(/properties)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as       
    MacAddress From Hardware Go

    <properties>
    <settings hwid="hardware">
     <setting typeid="928B6039-4E4A-4B03-9A82-A1CF29748ACC">
      <name>DetectedModelName</name>
      <value>AXIS P3365 Fixed Dome Network Camera</value>
     </setting>
    <setting typeid="DAF813F8-2E02-4AE5-9F0F-B0FB203D3CB6">
      <name>ProductID</name>
     <value>Axis2ChDevice</value>
    </setting>
    <setting typeid="F9D27CE8-8FA9-4B91-8C85-3E80DE7EF0AB">
      <name>MacAddress</name>
      <value>ACCC8E5EE927</value>
   </setting>
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: I have tried this it returns all values but I am not sure how to extract what i need.select uri, settings.value('(/properties)[1]', 'varchar(max)') as MacAddress
From Hardware
Go

Comment: Can you edit that into the question instead of putting code in comments?

Comment: Sure. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT s.c.value('./name[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS name,
      s.c.value('./value[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS val
FROM Hardware h
CROSS APPLY h.Settings.nodes('//setting') s(c)
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE name = 'MacAddress';
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fc503fc1215efb7e429a6d3cd625dd91)**

Answer (score 0):

The where condition i used is a little rough however if you are sure of your schema then you could use something like the below to return the MacAddress settings as a row:

```
declare @hardware xml = '<properties>
    <settings hwid="hardware">
        <setting typeid="928B6039-4E4A-4B03-9A82-A1CF29748ACC">
            <name>DetectedModelName</name>
            <value>AXIS P3365 Fixed Dome Network Camera</value>
        </setting>
        <setting typeid="DAF813F8-2E02-4AE5-9F0F-B0FB203D3CB6">
            <name>ProductID</name>
            <value>Axis2ChDevice</value>
        </setting>
        <setting typeid="F9D27CE8-8FA9-4B91-8C85-3E80DE7EF0AB">
            <name>MacAddress</name>
            <value>ACCC8E5EE927</value>
        </setting>
    </settings>
</properties>'

select 
    Hardware.Setting.value('./@typeid', 'nvarchar(50)') as 'TypeId',
    Hardware.Setting.value('(./name)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as 'SettingName',
    Hardware.Setting.value('(./value)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as 'SettingValue'
from @hardware.nodes('/properties/settings/setting') as Hardware(Setting)
where Hardware.Setting.value('(./name)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') = 'MacAddress'
```